# How can I display my created error list using csvhelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Apologies as this may seem a dumb question but I am missing something and not sure what to do.

As part of an application I'm making I am using CSVHelper for creating a file which contains details of any errors that may arise when using the application, such as a failure to connect to the database, values missing etc. I had been following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRaSeLYYrcQ and edited it more to suit my needs. I have an error logging file like so:

```
public class ErrorLogging
{
    public string ErrorType { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }



    public static List<ErrorLogging> GetErrors(string type, string relating, string message)
    {

        return new List<ErrorLogging>
        {
            new ErrorLogging
            {
                ErrorType = type,
                Relation = relating,
                Message = message

            }
        };

    }
}
```

So here I have made it so the column headers in the csv file will be ErrorType, Relating and Message

I also have an export log file:

```
class ExportLog
{
    public static void Log<T>(string path, string file, List<T>report)
    {
        var csvPath = Path.Combine(path + "\\", file);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(csvPath))
        {
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(report);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

In my main file program.cs I then use these by doing something like:

```
        if (validateRoleTitles is not false)
        {
            log.Information("Roles found");
        }

        else
        {
            log.Warning("Roles could not be found");
            ErrorLogging.GetErrors("Warning", "Database", "Not all roles found in the database");

        }
```

And I now need to create the csv file with the list of errors by doing something like:

```
 ExportLog.Log(config.ExportFolder, exportFile, "error logging list here");
```

However I'm not sure how to actually display these lists that I am creating if that makes sense?

As I can not do:

```
ExportLog.Log(config.ExportFolder, exportFile, ErrorLogging.GetErrors());
```

since it will be looking for parameters to be passed in. I know I am missing something very obvious here but can't figure out what, any help would be appreciated

Comment: This doesn't answer your question - have you considered using a logging library instead? Something like http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: I have been specifically asked to do this with csvhelper but that is something I will look into for my own personal use, thank you

Comment: Side note: `Path.Combine(path, file)`, not `Path.Combine(path + "\\", file)`

Comment: *list of errors* - but your list only contains one error? And when you call GetErrors you don't store the return?

Comment: Perhaps using some existing logging provision and writing a new output sink for it (if one doesn't already exist) that creates a CSV would be beneficial

Comment: There will be more than 1 error, it was just an example of it being used

Comment: *I know I am missing something very obvious here* - strikes me that the disconnect is that your class that is doing the work is calling GetErrors and thus receiving some list of ErrorLoggings that it has absolutely no interest in (nor should it *want* to be interested in what an ErrorLogging is and have to manage handing it off). If you were writing some simple hangman game and got an error that you just Console.WriteLine("blah") your hangman class forms a string and just kicks it out into WriteLine and then doesn't care what WriteLine does (maybe nothing).

Comment: Hangman doesn't call some method to receive a Stream and then have to know what to call on it cause the message to show up somewhere in the black area. The logging is supposed to abstract away that dependency from the class that does the work - the class that is doing the work knows 3 strings - `type`, `relating`, `message` - it wants to chuck those into something and not get back some custom type that it then has to be programmed to know how to deal with. Follow the pattern of the log.Information call (itself just taking a string, adding a severity level and passing it off to somewhere else)

Comment: .. and keep the flow of information away from the class that does the work. Have the errors collect in some cache and periodically dump it to disk (every 10th error? every passing second?), for example. If you use an existing looging - like you seem to have already with log.Information etc, then you can provide data into that, and you can provide an output channel that will collect the data and dump it to CSV. The logging provider will manage when to call your sink based on what you've told it about the severities it should be interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up solving my issue, I had been going about it the wrong way, I did not need to have:

```
public static List<ErrorLogging> GetErrors(string type, string relating, string message)
{

    return new List<ErrorLogging>
    {
        new ErrorLogging
        {
            ErrorType = type,
            Relation = relating,
            Message = message

        }
    };

}
```

in ErrorLogging.cs, it simply just needed to be:

```
public class ErrorLogging
{
    public string ErrorType { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

Then in program.cs I can declare a new list like so:

```
  List<ErrorLogging> ErrorList = new List<ErrorLogging>();
```

and then when there is a point I would need to add to the list I can simply do something along the lines of:

```
            ErrorList.Add(new ErrorLogging()
            {
                ErrorType = "Warning",
                Relation = "Database",
                Message = "Not all properties found in the database"
            });
```

And then when it comes to creating the csv with the list of errors, I can check whether the list is empty or not, if not empty then create:

```
       if (ErrorList.Any())
       {
            ExportLog.Log(config.LogFolder, errorLog, ErrorList);

        }
```